# Can I achieve underline and circle with css?

Tags: css

I want to achieve the following layout with the help of css. I want to be able to selectively underline text and draw circle around text elements.
This has somewhat of a chalk effect. Any pointers would be useful.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxIGl.png)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shapes.asp

Comment: _This has somewhat of a chalk effect_ .... not with CSS alone

Answer (score 0):

Yor can wrap the wanted word in span and then make this effect using pseudo elements:

HTML:

```
<p>Some Text with <span class="underline">underline</span> and <span class="circle">circle</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
.underline, .circle {
    position: relative;
}
.circle::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.underline::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

DEMO:
https://codepen.io/eliortabeka/pen/RdxVNX

NOTE:
You can change the circle type the any freehand drawing image you wish

Answer (score 0):

You want to have this freehand drawing effect right?
with css you can only make exact shapes that are not as handmade.
this effect you can do in two ways:
-Use images as background in the case of the circle and as image (`<img>`) in the case of the underline
-Using canvas, is an extensive and complex subject but it is the best way to solve your problem if you think about good practices
An example of the first way:

```
<div class="wrapper-text">
    <p>text circle</p>
</div>

.wrapper-text {
    width: 100px //width and height a little bigger than p tag
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url('/path-image-circle.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

you can also place an image tag inside the wrapper with `position: absolute` and format the width and height instead of using as background